# Using kustomize for manual CD vs tekton automated CI/CD

Tags: kubernetes, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, kustomize, tekton

What is the difference between using [Kustomize](https://kustomize.io/) and [Tekton](https://cloud.google.com/tekton/) for deployment?

To me it looks like Kustomize is a lightweight CI/CD client developer tool where you manually go in and do your CI/CD, where Tekton is automated CI/CD running within Kubernetes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kustomize is a tool for overriding (instead of templating) your Kubernetes manifest files. It it now built-in in kubectl with `kubectl apply -k`.

Tekton is a project for creating Kubernetes Custom Resources for building CICD pipelines of tasks on Kubernetes. One of the tasks in a pipeline can be an image with `kubectl` that apply the changes using Kustomize (`kubectl apply -k`).